# The Famous Last Words Square

Tags: cipher, video-games

After installing the newest MMO and creating a fresh character you spawn for the first time. After a quick look at the map, you see you are at The Famous Last Words Square. You quickly realize that the ground is covered by big letters arranged in a ... square:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| P   U   N   T   ~   U   U   R   J   ~   K   G |
|   +---------------------------------------+   |
| J | N   A   A   T   V   F   V   K   J   G | T |
|   |   +-------------------------------+   |   |
| I | ~ | V   J   ~   N   A   A   W   N | K | E |
|   |   |   +-----------------------+   |   |   |
| V | I | S | C   N   F   V   W   U | J | K | E |
|   |   |   |   +---------------+   |   |   |   |
| A | J | N | K | F   V   K   S | T | I | V | E |
|   |   |   |   |   +-------+   |   |   |   |   |
| ~ | K | I | K | U | Z   Q | V | V | K | T | E |
|   |   |   |   |   +---+   |   |   |   |   |   |
| J | N | W | U | X   ~   H | ~ | N | Z | W | E |
|   |   |   |   +-----------+   |   |   |   |   |
| N | Q | T | E   I   T   U   W | I | X | V | E |
|   |   |   +-------------------+   |   |   |   |
| O | U | Z   J   G   U   O   I   Z | I | K | E |
|   |   +---------------------------+   |   |   |
| I | P   A   A   N   ~   S   V   O   I | ~ | E |
|   +-----------------------------------+   |   |
| V   A   W   T   Z   O   V   S   I   V   A | E |
+-------------------------------------------+   |
| E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Not far away you see an NPC with an exclamation mark above his head, so you decide to talk to him:

> Every time a hero dies a horrible death the last words he said become alive. Some of this words gathered at this place and formed the letters on the ground. However only the wisest heroes can decipher them.
> There is also a legend about this square. If someone can decipher the hidden phrases the name of a creature will appear. Saying its name 3 times will make the one incredibly rich.

---

**Decipher the hidden phrases and find out the name of the creature.**

**Hint:**

> There is more than one reason for the E's at the bottom and right side:
> - they are needed to fill the square
> - they are part of a "phrase"
> - they show how the phrases are arranged in the square

Comment: I'm honestly surprised there isn't the classic "wssswwwsswsasaawsasawsdaddadsd123123123421352524351234" line uttered by many characters as they died.

Comment: @Kingrames Actually you are pretty close to one of the quotes. ;)

Comment: I know what I want the quote containing the E's to be... but there's only 21 E's in the grid, and my quote requires exactly 22.  I must be formatting it wrong somehow, because there's no way the quote I'm thinking of isn't in there...  A mystery, indeed.

Comment: @Zerris I'm afraid you are on the wrong track. This quote could contain more or less E's without changing it significantly. Look at Kingrames comment to explain why.

Comment: What are the blanks in the square? And for `last words`, do you mean the last letters of different vocabularies?

Comment: @SeraphCheng Apparently there were changes on SE which completely messed up the formatting. I'll update the question when I'm back from work. The term [Last Words is explained here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_words). The black squares separate different quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking in the wrong directions for months! Please feel free to suggest an edit.

> Starting centre at the square, moving outwards clockwise, and separating each set of words by ~ (formerly black square) leads to the phrases below.
>
>  **encrypted → decrypted (using letter substitution from frequency analysis and guessing)**
>
>  1. ZQH  → AFK [away from keyboard]
>  2. XUFVKSV → COVER ME
>  3. WUTIEUKKCNFVWUTVNIZIOUGJZTWINSVJ → DONT WORRY IVE DONE IT A THOUSAND TIMES
>  4. NAAWNJIKZXIIOVS → ILL DISTRACT THEM
>  5. NAAPUQNKJI → ILL GO FIRST
>  6. NAATVFVKJGKKVTWVK → ILL NEVER SURRENDER
>  7. AVISVOZTWAVIONJ → LET ME HANDLE THIS
>  8. AVIJPUNT → LETS GO IN
>  9. UURJ → OOPS
>  10. KGTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE → RUNWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW [see Dave Andersen's comment]

As for the creature's name...

> Comparing plaintext to ciphertext alphabet, a sequence of letters that looks like a name appears in the latter. Instead of KLMNOP, we get
>
>  [HASTUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hastur) the Unspeakable One

I'll pass on the riches.

Comment: W is the move forward key in a lot of popular MMO games, so the last one is run and then the action of running, but instead of actually running the player said w a lot (key repeat, they were holding it) and since they stood still, they died.

Comment: Well done! If you take a closer look at the alphabet the name of the creature should stare in your face.

Comment: Thanks, @DaneAndersen!
Thank you, @Sleafar! Again, I've looked in the wrong place. I think I got it.

Comment: Shortly after speaking the name three times [you prepare for a respawn](http://www.wfrp.de/hosted/flw/en/flws.txt). ;)